# R Studio is not refreshing sourced files

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I'm using R Studio in version 1.2.5033 and I develop with R Shiny. Sometimes when I add a new function to a file, which is not my main R-file, my main R-file isn't seeing it. I'm using modules and when I restart R-Studio everything is back to normal.

Lets imagine I create a Shiny App with 3 files:
- ui.R
- server.R
- data.R

My server.R starts with the following lines:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
library(data.table)
library(modules)

data <- modules::use("data.R")
```

Now I add a new function, stop my app and hit "Run App" again and I got an error in the console informing me, that the new function can't be found. When I

```
print(data)
```

it is not showing my new function. So there is no spelling mistake or something like this. This only happens, when I try to use functions from different files with modules or with source(...).
Is there some kind of weird caching in R Studio, that I'm not aware of? I'm pretty new to R so maybe I'm missing some important concepts or maybe I make some fundamental mistake.

I tried googling and stackoverflowing my problem but couldn't find a solution. I tried in R Studio "Restart R" and "Clear workspace" and both were not helping. The only thing which worked, is restarting R Studio completely. 
I'm open for any ideas and grateful for every help.

Comment: You need to re-read that module every time something changes in it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Could you tell me, what this means? I thought using this line: "data <- modules::use("data.R")" would already load the file in its newest version.

Comment: Because it's in the global namespace you need to reload it `data <- modules::use("data.R")` every time you make changes to it.